# Disable consent in oauth2 implicit grant type

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2-identity-server

We are evaluating WSO2IS as the Identity Server for many coorporate apps (web/mobile) using OAuth2.

For the web apps (server side) we use grant type password with user credentials and clientId/Key per
web apps, everytings works fine, user consent is not asked by Oauth2 in this scenario.

But for JS Apps and mobile we need to switch to Implicit Grant Type as the clientKey cannot be securely stored.
In the Implicit grant type scenario, the user consent is asked, although I don't get why as we are in a 
corporate environnement, it's strange to ask a user to consent to access user corporate profile.

Is there a workaround to disable user consent ?

In identity.xml, I see there is a  :

```
<OAuth2ConsentPage>${carbon.protocol}://${carbon.host}:${carbon.management.port}/authenticationendpoint/oauth2_authz.do</OAuth2ConsentPage>
```

but leaving this parameter to empty or something else is not working, this is probably hardcoded in the oauth2 app endpoint.

If you have a solution, please let me know
Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting SkipUserConsent to false in identity.xml

```
<SkipUserConsent>false</SkipUserConsent>
```